# Laravel One to Many Relationships Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently going through the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) and I'm a bit stuck on the relationships section, mainly the One to Many query.

Currently I have 2 tables, one for `customers` and another for `orders`. My end goal is to fetch all values where `orders.cust_id = customers.id`. They have a foreign key relationship.

I've tried following the documentation but implementing it into the controller. So I ended up with something like:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function customer($id)
    {
        $orders = Customer::find($id)->orders;
        echo $orders;
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach($orders as $order)
        {
            echo '<li>' . $order->name . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

and in the routes, I used this to connect the controller `Route::get('customer/{id}', 'CustomerController@customer');`

Now in my customer model, I have the following which I assume takes the id parameter from the route section.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'cust_id');
    }
}
```

All it's returning is `[]` despite the tables being correctly populated. I then tried to simplify it by just using the routes option (no controller)

```
Route::get('customer/{id}', function($id) {
    $orders = App\Customer::find($id)->orders;
    echo $orders;
});
```

but I get the same output. I can however, do the inverse section of the documentation and retrieve the customer information of the order

```
Route::get('orders', function() {
   $orders = App\Order::all();
   foreach ($orders as $order) {
       echo $order->name . " for " . $order->customer['name'] . "<br/>";
    }
});


class Order extends Model
{
    public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction so that I can retrieve all orders with the customer id provided? Thanks.

Comment: Not that it matters, but you're mixing MVC (model, view and controller) stuff. Now for the problem try to do the following and tell the output. `$customer= Customer::find($id);` and on the next line `dd($customer);`. Place these two lines before `$orders = Customer::find($id)->orders;`. This is to see if the controller finds the customer at all

Comment: Yeah it is finding the customer. Currently have it in a view using `return view('customer', compact('customer'));` and it will display other attributes of the customer, just not the orders.

Comment: Do you have a corresponding customer() method on your orders table?

Comment: To see the last query that was run you can use `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` Add this line after `$orders = Customer::find($id)->orders;` and check if you're query is correct

Comment: @btl Is it required to have the inverse? AFAIK it isn't required

Comment: If 'cust_id' is the name of the foreign key field on your order model, then it might be required, but I'm not 100% certain. The normal naming convention would be customer_id. It's worth trying in your case.

Comment: @davejal Yeah, I do have the inverse setup for customer.

Comment: I don't think the inverse has anything to do with your problem. It's either the name of the field is wrong or the specific customer id isn't found in your db. As @btl already said in his comment, could you maybe change the `cust_id` to `customer_id` and remove `, 'cust_id'` from your controller

Comment: @davejal Still the same thing happening

Comment: @btl Yeah I do have the inverse (meant to tag you in previous comment) and it is working.

Comment: By using either tinker or your code, try this and see if you are getting the customer information - `App\Order::where('cust_id', $id)->get();`  (The id here is the customer id for which you are invoking the request) As the above commenters said, it may be due to lack of data, but the above query will make it clear.

Comment: I can run a normal MySQL query with `select * from orders where customer_id =1` and it returns the expected results as well as the above query (`App\Order::where('customer_id', $id)->get();`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the keys in the database. Because the primary key was `ID` rather than `id`, I needed to specify this in the `hasMany` as the third parameter. So in the model, it should have looked like:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order', `cust_id`, `ID`);
    }
}
```

It's probably easier just to change the `ID` to `id` but I of course didn't think it would make a difference or even really consider its affect.